# function retornando NaN deixando de realizar o cálculo

Tags: javascript, matemática

Em uma calculadora solar, tudo funciona, menos o valor final que retorna NaN. Onde está meu erro?

```
function calcular(valorInformado) {

    ResultPotencia = parseFloat(valorInformado * 8.28 / 1000).toFixed(2);

    ResultModulos = parseInt(ResultPotencia * 8.28 / 1000);

    ResultArea = parseFloat(ResultModulos * 2);

    Result1 = parseFloat(11 * ResultPotencia * 0.85 * 1000).toFixed(3);

    Result2 = parseFloat(11 * ResultPotencia * 1.10 * 1000).toFixed(3);



    var elemResult = document.getElementById("resultadopotencia");
    elemResult.innerText = " " + ResultPotencia + " KWp" ;

    var elemResult = document.getElementById("resultadomodulos");
    elemResult.innerText = " " + parseInt(ResultPotencia * 1000 / 265) + " Módulos"; 

    var elemResult = document.getElementById("resultadometros");
    elemResult.innerText = " " + (ResultPotencia * 1000 / 265 * 2).toFixed(1) + " M²"; 

    var elemResult = document.getElementById("valorsistema");
    elemResult.innerText = " " + (ResultIntermediario * ResultPotencia * 0.85 * 1000).toFixed(2).formatMoney();

    var elemResult = document.getElementById("valorsistema2");
    elemResult.innerText = " " + (ResultIntermediario * ResultPotencia * 1.10 * 1000).toFixed(2).formatMoney();

}

ResultIntermediario = function() {
    var ResultIntermediario = this;

    if(ResultPotencia <= 3)
    ResultIntermediario = 11;

    if(ResultPotencia >= 3)
    ResultIntermediario = 9;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom consegui achar os erros, refiz o código para debugar ele no navegador, você cometeu um equívoco simples na função:

```
ResultIntermediario = function() {
var ResultIntermediario = this;

if(ResultPotencia <= 3)
ResultIntermediario = 11;

if(ResultPotencia >= 3)
ResultIntermediario = 9;}
```

Você não especificou nenhum parametro e nenhum retorno, por isso na hora do calculo você obtinha NaN, que é a referência para nulo. Eu a modifiquei da seguinte forma:

```
ResultIntermediario = function(ResultPotencia) {

if(ResultPotencia <= 3) return 11 * ResultPotencia;

if(ResultPotencia >= 3) return 9 * ResultPotencia;}
```

Agora ela recebe um parâmetro e retorna um valor * o Resultado da potência (Vi que você tinha usado a função * result potência no Inner HTML e deduzi isso).

Segue o código completo, testei no meu navegador e tudo funcionou, você só precisa adicionar o Inner HTML e os format novamente pois eu não tinha essas funções criadas.

```
function calcular(valorInformado) {

ResultPotencia = parseFloat(valorInformado * 8.28 / 1000).toFixed(2);

ResultModulos = parseInt(ResultPotencia * 8.28 / 1000);

ResultArea = parseFloat(ResultModulos * 2);

Result1 = parseFloat(11 * ResultPotencia * 0.85 * 1000).toFixed(3);

Result2 = parseFloat(11 * ResultPotencia * 1.10 * 1000).toFixed(3);

var elemResult = document.getElementById("resultadopotencia");
console.log(ResultPotencia + " KWp" );

var elemResult = document.getElementById("resultadomodulos");
console.log(parseInt(ResultPotencia * 1000 / 265) + " Módulos"); 

var elemResult = document.getElementById("resultadometros");
console.log((ResultPotencia * 1000 / 265 * 2).toFixed(1) + " M²"); 

var elemResult = document.getElementById("valorsistema");
console.log((ResultIntermediario(ResultPotencia) * 0.85 * 1000));

var elemResult = document.getElementById("valorsistema2");
console.log(ResultIntermediario(ResultPotencia) * 1.10 * 1000);}
```